# Android ArrayAdapter gives newly scrolled item

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, textview

I have an ArrayAdapter which shows some posts using a fragment. In this fragment I have some buttons. So all of the posts shown have these buttons.
The problem is, when I click a button of a post to setText to a field of this post; instead of changing text of post that I clicked, it changes text of newly scrolled item.
For example if I scroll down the ListView a new item comes. Then regardless of which post I clicked it changes text of this new post.
How can I prevent this to happen? I take current post using

```
getItem(position)
```

By scroolling I mean new element of the list are loaded and shown.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comment_small,parent,false);
    TextView tvOwner = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvCommentSmallOwner);
    TextView tvCreationDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvCommentSmallCreationDate);
    TextView tvCreationDateValue = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvCommentSmallCreationDate);
    TextView tvContent = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvCommentSmallContent);
    tvVoteCount = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvCommentVoteCount);
    c = getItem(position);
    tvOwner.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.generic_by) + " " + c.getOwnerId());
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    String s  =c.getPostDate();
    System.out.println(s);
    tvCreationDateValue.setText(s);
    tvContent.setText(c.getContent());
    btnDownVote = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.btnCommentDownVote);
    btnUpVote = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.btnCommentUpVote);


    tvVoteCount.setText("" + c.getNetCount());
    btnUpVote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            c=getItem(position);
            ServerRequests sr = new ServerRequests(getContext());
            MemberLocalStore memberLocalStore = new MemberLocalStore(getContext());
            Member m = memberLocalStore.getLoggedInMember();
            sr.voteComment(c, true, m.getId(), new Consumer<String>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(String vote) {
                    tvVoteCount.setText("" + vote);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    btnDownVote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            c=getItem(position);
            ServerRequests sr = new ServerRequests(getContext());
            MemberLocalStore memberLocalStore = new       MemberLocalStore(getContext());
            Member m = memberLocalStore.getLoggedInMember();
            sr.voteComment(c, false, m.getId(), new Consumer<String>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(String vote) {
                    tvVoteCount.setText("" + vote);
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

[image: ListView]

I want to vote (like,dislike) some posts but when I click upvote button that marked as 1, overall vote of the post that marked as 2 changes.

Comment: can you post the getView ?

Comment: 1. Post more code. 
2. What does 'scrool' mean?

Comment: you need to set color of item in getView by state of item

Comment: You'll need to show more code on how you pick the item to update (e.g. where does "position" come from?)

Comment: I edited and added some code